SVN merge merging old revisions
Trying to merge trunk into my branch.
mergeinfo in the branch is simply: /root/trunk:37185-37889
No subtree has any mergeinfo.
(This is other information in mergeinfo regarding other branches, which I assume is not relevant.)
When merging, the output gives:
--- Merging r37185 through r37190 into 'subfolder':
and then it runs into silly conflicts based on these old-no-longer-relevant revisions.
Why is it trying to merge these revisions in again, since mergeinfo clearly specifies that they were already merged in?

It seems like the mergeinfo in your branch is not being respected properly, which is why it's attempting to merge changes that should already be considered merged. This issue can occur due to a few reasons:

Corrupted or Inconsistent Mergeinfo : Sometimes the mergeinfo can become inconsistent or corrupted, causing SVN to incorrectly determine which revisions need merging.

Subfolder-Specific Mergeinfo : If there are specific mergeinfo properties on subfolders or files that are not correctly aligned with the root, SVN might try to merge revisions unnecessarily. Even though you mentioned no subtree has any mergeinfo, it's worth double-checking.

Changes Outside the Tracked Path : If changes were made outside the tracked path or in paths that were not initially included in the merge, SVN might attempt to reapply them.


To troubleshoot and resolve this issue, you can try the following steps:

Inspect Mergeinfo : Double-check the mergeinfo on both your branch and the trunk, as well as any subfolders, to ensure consistency.

svn propget svn:mergeinfo -R


Clean Up Mergeinfo : If you find any discrepancies, you might need to clean up the mergeinfo. You can manually adjust the svn
property using svn propedit or svn propset.

Record Merges Manually : If the problem persists, you can manually record the problematic revisions as merged, bypassing the actual merge process.


svn merge --record-only -c 37185-37190 ^/root/trunk


Reintegrate the Branch : If the branch has diverged significantly and the mergeinfo is causing continuous issues, it might be worthwhile to reintegrate the branch afresh.

svn merge --reintegrate ^/root/trunk


Check for SVN Updates : Ensure you are using the latest version of SVN, as bugs and issues with mergeinfo handling can sometimes be resolved in newer versions.

By carefully inspecting and adjusting the mergeinfo properties, you should be able to resolve the conflicts and ensure that only the necessary revisions are merged.

Did you use ChatGPT? Your answer is very similar to what AI gave me. Much is also not relevant.
"Corrupted or Inconsistent Mergeinfo" - since I posted the contents of my mergeinfo, you can see it's not corrupted.
"Subfolder-Specific Mergeinfo" - I explained that no subfolder has mergeinfo.
"Inspect Mergeinfo" - um, read the question.
